# Why data is sent as thousands of small chunks

Tags: web

when data is sent across the Web, it is sent as thousands of small chunks, so that many different web users can download the same website at the same time. If web sites were sent as single big chunks, only one user could download one at a time, which obviously would make the Web very inefficient and not much fun to use.

I simply don't understant why  data is sent as thousands of small chunks  the explanation above is not an answer for me also..

Answer (score 1):

It's because that's how computer networks work. The internet protocol has limited-size packets, and you need to divide everything into these to get it transferred across the internet.

> so that many different web users can download the same website at the same time.

This doesn't make sense. The packet-based nature of the internet has nothing to do with websites being delivered to multiple users at once.

Think about it like this: if things weren't cut up into small packets, than a single error would destroy everything you've transferred, instead of just forcing the receiving end to ask for a single, broken packet again.

Comment: now that makes sense , can u recommend any reliable sites about computer networks coz i suspect that I'm reading bullshit for about 2 hours..

Comment: Didem, I'd recommend Computer Networks 5e (Tanenbaum). [Here's a link](http://it341-f14-bird.wikispaces.umb.edu/file/view/Computer+Networks+-+A+Tanenbaum+-+5th+edition.pdf)

Comment: @JamesPaterson that *certainly* is a classic. I think OP should at least read chapter 1 and there, especially the concept of layers